# Has anyone successfully mounted other lenses on Ricoh GR Digital II?

Tags: diy, old-lenses, macro-converter

I've been given a Ricoh GR Digital II to play with — sort of a long term loan really. *Lovely* little camera. In the past I've messed about with Olympus film and digital, and Nikon compacts and SLRs with other manufacturer's lenses using converter rings and reverse mounts (for super macro effects).

I'd like to try something similar, but I can't see any evidence that others have tried this online, and can't find any converter rings or etc.

Any thoughts? The GR II is so good in terms of features and the 10MP ccd etc, I'd love to hack it a bit in terms of optics.

Comment: I'd like to reply: No. And this would still be a valid reply... Not being a smart-ass but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ricoh GR Digital II is not an interchangable-lens camera.   So the only alternative/additional lenses you can use with it are the conversion lenses GW-1 (wide, 21mm) / GT-1 (tele, 40mm) and the GH-1 hood adapter.

I'm not sure which other lens adapters will fit the GH-1.   Perhaps your camera manual specifies the thread size for the GH-1, which will allow you to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks James, I didn't think about utilising the GH-1. Need to get hold of one now :)

Comment: I've never used this camera so don't know for sure that that would be useful to you.